# Overflow menu icon (three vertical dots) visible in Apps in HTC One X and not in Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-one-x, menu

I have HTC One X while my friend has Samsung Galaxy S2. In some Apps like Google Chrome in my phone the Overflow menu icon (three vertical dots) are visible while on SGS2 they are not.

[image: Google Chrome in HTC One X with Overflow menu icon (three vertical dots)]

Google Chrome in HTC One X with Overflow menu icon (three vertical dots)

[image: Google Chrome in Samsung Galaxy S2 without Overflow menu icon]

Google Chrome in Samsung Galaxy S2 without Overflow menu icon

In my HOX I have set the setting of "Recent apps button" to "Press for menu, press and hold for recent apps". So when I press recent apps button it shows the menu, so the menu icon should be hidden, right?

Why is the menu icon visible on HTC One X and not on Samsung Galaxy S2?

Comment: Ugh. Could you trim those images?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug.  The "Make the recent apps button act like a menu button" setting appears to not be changing the appropriate values to inform apps that a permanent menu button exists and thus apps act as if it doesn't have the menu button.

[ViewConfiguration](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#L291) is what handles that.