# Unable to change tab in Google Chrome when swiping from side to side on the toolbar

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, htc-one-x

I have Google Chrome v35.0.1916.141 installed on my HTC One X running Android 4.2.2 with HTC Sense 5. One of the previous updates introduced a nifty feature to change tabs by swiping from side to side on the toolbar. But now with the current version this is not working.

I cannot find any setting to turn this feature on/off. Has this feature been removed?

*Update*

I checked on HTC Desire 500 and it works there.

Comment: Can you swipe downwards to show all the tabs out of curiosity? I've noticed Chrome loads different on HTC devices. It has the 3 dot menu, but on a galaxy S4, no menu there. The functionaility is still present in the latest build here on S4 and Nexus anyway.

Comment: @RossC: Yes I can do that. I have updated my question with my new findings.

Comment: @RossC It wouldn't have the overflow menu on an S4, because that device has a physical menu button. That's how Android works.

Comment: @danhulme so does my HTC but that does have overflow, sense UI interfering?

Comment: @RossC Do other apps show overflow menus, or just Chrome? If other apps have it too, it sounds like a deliberate choice on HTC's part.

Comment: @DanHulme: Yes it seems a deliberate choice and I even [raised a question reagrding this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47124/30106). But I think we would be digressing from the topic here if we discuss about overflow icon. Have you encountered this problem mentioned in my question on your phone?

Comment: No, it works perfectly on my Galaxy S3, same version of Chrome.

Comment: Works fine on Google Edition, not fine on HTC Sense UI, seems to be a HTC thing. It's a bit random what apps it effefts though. Weird.

Comment: Got fixed in version 36.0.1985.128!