# Can a user read crash logs on Android?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, crashes, htc-one-x, logging

I have HTC One X running Android 4.2.2 with HTC Sense 5. Lately I have been encountering some [wierd issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/73279/30106). And the most irritating of them is that my phone keeps crashing randomly. By uninstalling/installing one app at a time I was able to figure out that Viber was one major cause of that issue. Some other causes that I have been able to figure out are updating apps on my phone while the phone is being charged (yes that sounds stupid but 50% of my crashes happen during that time), playing Candy Crush and receive some notification, and more.

I want to know is there a way I can read the crash logs without rooting the phone? And if I can, how can analyse and find the root cause (app) of problem?

Comment: You might wish to investigate our [`logging` tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info). Especially see: [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575) & [How can I access android log files on my Nexus 7 without root access?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28857/16575)